# Can I combine variables into a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var submitHandler = function ($link, $form, close) {

   var val = $form.valid();
   var action = $form.attr('data-action')
   var entity = $form.attr('data-entity')
   var href = $form.attr('data-href');
   var rownum = $link.attr('data-row');
   var $row = $('#row_' + rownum);
   var $submitBt = $('.block-footer button:contains("Submit")');
   .....
   .....
   jsonSuccessModal(action, rownum, close, $form, $submitBt, $row);

}

function jsonSuccessModal(action, rownum, close, $form, $submitBt, $row) {
    ...
}
```

Rather than have many parameters is there a way I could combine variables 
in the first code block and then just send an object that represents the 
combination to the jsonSuccessModal. Something like an anonymous object ?

Comment: `{key: value, key2: value2, etc: what, have: you, tried: questionmark}`

Comment: @RobW. Wow, if that was an answer you had the `Enlightened` badge in less than 3 minutes. Nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var submitHandler = function (data) {
    data.link; // Do something...
    data.form; // Do something...
    ...
};

submitHandler({
    link: "foo",
    form: "form",
    close: "close"
});​
```

Comment: I dont want to be a necromancer, but the reason for the downvote probably is, that this code can't work as is. having a `var` keyword in front of a function call?

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own object and send that over. it would also be easier when wanting to access the data.
http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/objects shows how to make your own object

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern i've come to use on functions that take a lot of parameters (uses jQuery, though):

```
var myFunc = function (parameters) {
    // any parameters not passed will be defaulted here
    parameters = $.extend({
        foo: 1,
        bar: 'hello',
        biz: false
    }, parameters || {}); // default parameters to an empty object if it is not passed at all

    // use the parameters like you normally would
    var answer = 6 + parameters.foo;
};

// call the function using an object
myFunc({ foo: 2, bar: 'goodbye'}); // notice biz will be defaulted to false
```

if you do not want to use jquery, you can use something like this instead of `$.extend` (untested)

```
var extend = function (defaultObject, sourceObject) {
    for (var key in defaultObject) {
        if (!sourceObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            sourceObject[key] = defaultObject[key];
        }
    }
    return sourceObject;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In the general case the answer to your question is NO -- javascript doesn't support keyword arguments unpacking like e.g. in Python (`**kwargs`). You could try "extending" Javascript to support this kind of feature, but the code will be rather awkward (since this language has no reflection support either):

```
function paramNames(func) {
    return func.toString().match(/\(([^)]+)\)/)[1].split(/[\s,]+/)
}

function callWithKwargs(func, args, thisptr) {
    return func.apply(thisptr || this,
        paramNames(func).map(function(e) { return args[e] }));
}

// example:

function foo(bar, baz, spam) {
    console.log('bar', bar, 'baz', baz, spam, 'spam'); 
}

callWithKwargs(foo, {
    spam: 'bacon',
    baz: 'hello',
    bar: 'barbar'
})
```

That said, if the function in question is yours, you can simply pass an object to it as already suggested.

Answer (score -2):

Yes you could do it like below

```
var submitHandler = function ($link, $form, close) {
   var obj ={
 val = $form.valid();
 action = $form.attr('data-action')
 entity = $form.attr('data-entity')
 href = $form.attr('data-href');
 rownum = $link.attr('data-row');
 $row = $('#row_' + rownum);
 $submitBt = $('.block-footer button:contains("Submit")');};
   jsonSuccessModal(obj);

}
```

Comment: How would I access the parameters in the jsonSuccessModel function?

Comment: javascript objects must be key-value pairs, your syntax is a little off.